# print on screen long scientific variables in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to echo in bash a variable

```
var1=1
var2=0.25471686e+03
```

like this

```
echo "LHAPDF::alphasPDF($var1*$var2)"

LHAPDF::alphasPDF(1*
0.25471686e+03^2);
```

So, my problem is that for long scientific numbers in var2, it prints the result in two lines... How can I avoid it?

I would like to be:

```
LHAPDF::alphasPDF(1*0.25471686e+03^2);
```

Comment: Assuming the missing double quote from `echo` command is a typo, then there is no reason for the split line here in `bash`. And where does the `^0` come from?

Comment: Are the first two lines part of a script? Has it been written in Windows, perhaps?

Comment: yeah, the missing " was a typo - The ^ acts as "power" but does not matter --I just want to pipe the output to be used in some c++ .

Comment: I know what it means but that doesn't explain where it came from, it's not stored in `var2` nor is it in your `echo` command, this issue isn't reproducible are you sure you copy the issue correctly?

Comment: Ok, found it...Should have wrapped quotes around the ( ie  

echo LHAPDF::alphasPDF"("$var1*$var2")"

Comment: Sure quoting only the brackets was needed!? :| that isn't valid.. n.m.

Comment: @Alexis you can post that as answer to your own question.

Comment: Do you want to print the string `LHAPDF::alphasPDF(1*0.2547)` or do you want to calculate the floating point multiplication?